# Forking the upstream into a new branch

Tags: git, fork, branch

I have a forked repo `origin` with some changes and the `upstream` repo has some new changes. I don't want to merge my commits at this moment, but instead I wanted to create a new branch which has the same HEAD as that of `upstream`. Like forking the `upstream` into a new branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch upstream and declare a branch from (for instance) `upstream/master`:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout -b mybranch upstream/master
```

Or, if you don't want to switch to the new branch:

```
git branch --set-upstream mybranch upstream/master
```

Don't forget that a good practice is to rebase your changes on top of `upstream/master`, in order to make any future pull request easy to integrate (fast-forward merge)